# How to host Teams onlinemeeting using MS Graph API from web Apllications

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

In our project we are trying to integrate Microsoft teams with web application.Using MS Graph API i have created Online meeting and obtained id and joinurl of meeting and stored in db,the user will not get to know about meeting url . is there any way to start the MS Teams online meeting from webapplication and after leaving the meeting the person should automatically redirected to same webapplication.

usecase will be to create a onlinemeeting and join the meeting directly from application.

I have implemented this usecase for Zoom Meeting,is there any plugin or some other things available for **MS Teams online meeting** to implement this useCase in Angular and jsp.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation. It talks about you can [choose an API in Microsoft Graph to create and join online meetings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/choose-online-meeting-api) and get it started as well.

Comment: Hi @pk034 This question will be tracked from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/412548/how-to-host-teams-onlinemeeting-using-ms-graph-api.html).